# VBA-code does not look through hidden rows for adding a row with tracking number

Tags: vba, excel

I have another question which I hope to resolve with your help.

**What do I want to do.**
I use Excel to track my work, activities, contacts, et cetera. While doing that I found I was doing a lot of repetitive work in adding rows at the end of a sheet called "Activities".

What I want to do is this:
 - Press a button and adding a row.
 - Increase the trackingnumber with 1
 - Insert default values

**The code.**
To automate this, I have found (copy, pasted, adjusted it to my needs) the following code:

```
 Sub AddRowActiviteiten_NewAtEnd()
'Add's a new row at the end of the sheet.

Dim wsActiviteiten As Worksheet
Set wsActiviteiten = Sheets("Activiteiten")

DefType = "Daily"
DefStatus = "Open"
DefIssue = "*****"
DefImpact = "*****"
DefPrio = "Laag"
MyDate = Date

wsActiviteiten.Range("A4").Value = "1"

'Copy the "One Row To Rule Them All"
wsActiviteiten.Range("A3:Q3").Copy

wsActiviteiten.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

'Stop the "copy-action"
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Increase the tracking number with "one"
LastNumber = wsActiviteiten.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
wsActiviteiten.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = LastNumber + 1

'Insert default values
LastRow = wsActiviteiten.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row
Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = DefType
Cells(LastRow + 1, 3) = DefStatus
Cells(LastRow + 1, 4) = DefIssue
Cells(LastRow + 1, 5) = DefImpact
Cells(LastRow + 1, 6) = DefPrio
Cells(LastRow + 1, 8) = MyDate

'Step down 1 row from present location.
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End Sub
```

**The problem.**
In this sheet I open new items, but I also close them. I do this by changing their status and hide them from view. And this is the point where it goes wrong. When I close the *last item* on the list and want to add a new row, the macro adds a *new row* below the *last visible* entry. It does not find the last entry I have just hidden. And also, when this happens, adding the default values to the new row does not work. It adds them at the row above the added one.

Somehow this makes perfect sense. I tell the macro to look for the last entry, but what I don't understand is why it looks at the last *visible* entry and why it does not look in the hidden rows.

**To replicate.** Copy the code into a sheet (maybe you need to change the name of the sheet) and add a few lines. Put some info in the last row and hide it. Add another few lines and see what happens.

**The solution.** Is there a way to resolve this? Maybe there is a smarter way of doing things? I looked into things, but mostly I got results using "("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)". A loop could work, but I am afraid that 1) It does not search through hidden rows and 2) it makes the sheet (somewhat) sluggish. I must say I have tried to make a loop, first I want to see if my first solution is salvageable.

Thank you for your input, if there are any questions please let me know.

Simon
**EDIT: Working code for anyone interested**

```
  Sub AddRowActiviteiten_NewAtEnd()
'Add's a new row at the end of the sheet.

Dim wsActiviteiten As Worksheet
Set wsActiviteiten = Sheets("Activiteiten")

DefType = "Daily"
DefStatus = "Open"
DefIssue = "*****"
DefImpact = "*****"
DefPrio = "Laag"
MyDate = Date

'Copy the One Row To Rule Them All
wsActiviteiten.Range("A3:Q3").Copy

'Offset(y,x)
'De -16 is een getal dat iets doet, maar ik weet niet wat.
wsActiviteiten.Range(Split(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Address, ":")(1)).Offset(1, -16).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

'Stop the "copy-action"
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Het volgnummer verhogen met 1
'Het laatste getal selecteren (LastNumber) en dan plus 1.
LastNumber = wsActiviteiten.Range(Split(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Address, ":")(1)).Offset(0, -16).Value
wsActiviteiten.Range(Split(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Address, ":")(1)).Offset(1, -16).Value = LastNumber + 1

'Insert default values
LastRow = wsActiviteiten.Range(Split(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Address, ":")(1)).Offset(-1, 0).Row
Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = DefType
Cells(LastRow + 1, 3) = DefStatus
Cells(LastRow + 1, 4) = DefIssue
Cells(LastRow + 1, 5) = DefImpact
Cells(LastRow + 1, 6) = DefPrio
Cells(LastRow + 1, 8) = MyDate

'Step down 1 row from present location.
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I am going to use your question as an example of how to ask a question.

Comment: Perhaps [MSDN - SpecialCells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) might help. Particularly `xlCellTypeLastCell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update*

I see your sheet has an autofilter "hiding" the status rows - which `Find` wont detect, unlike hidden rows.

Suggest you try this updated code below:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng1 As Range
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range(Split(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Address, ":")(1)).Row
Else
    Set rng1 = Columns("A:A").Find("*", [a1], xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then MsgBox rng1.Row
End If
End Sub
```

*initial post*

If you are hiding rows then you can use `Find` with the `xlFormulas` option to find entries in hidden rows (unlike `xlValues`).

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Columns("A:A").Find("*", [a1], xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
MsgBox rng1.Address
```

Comment: I am trying to use this specific code in a seperate module on my sheet. When I hide one row, this macro turns up with location of the next value up, but not the hidden one. When reading up on xlFormulas it should turn up a value from a hidden location. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: @simon are you able to upload a sample workbook (to the cloud etc)?

Comment: Sure, here you go: we.tl/smyHLFDM49. I have added your code to the sheet already. (this is the second link, the other was not good).

Comment: @simon pls try this updated code. File was useful :)

Comment: Thank you for the working code. This is stuff I have not used before, so I am going to see if I can understand what is happening and how I can use it in my code. 

I am going on a trip in a few day's time, if I have not responded by then I will respond when I come. I appreciate it that you are taking the time to help me and I believe it's only fair that I reply to you when I have cracked this nut. For now I am not going to mark it as answered, since I need to understand and apply this first.

Cheers,
Simon

Comment: It works! With some local help I managed to get it working in my sheet. Can you explain what the code does? We could not fully understand it. As far as I understand it is that Split locates the empty row under a range of data. What Range(1) means we could not find out. There are other elements that go beyond my VBA-skills, but I am fairly certain that with time that will become clear. Also, on another sheet I tried to use the code, but that one has formula's in cells and this method sees formula's and goes to the next line to paste. But that is another question for later.Cheers, Simon

Comment: @simon This line returns the range of the autofilter `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Address`. The split breaks up the range, and then returns the second portion (ie C10 if the range was C1:C10). `Split(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Address, ":")(0))` would return the  first portion C1. Range then makes an address of this.

Comment: can you help me with another question that is related to this one? It would help me out a lot, cheers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120212/copying-and-adding-a-row-to-the-end-of-the-sheet-with-an-autofilter-enabled-and

Answer (score 2):

Say we have a status column  **AB** and we currently close an item by placing the word "Closed" in that column and then hiding the row.

**Instead:**

1. Unhide **all** rows
2. Perform any required inserts and edits
3. Via a loop, hide all rows marked "Closed"

Comment: Thank you for your comment Gary's Student. I can see how this can work on my sheet. But I have to ask, to perform these actions everytime I add a row, will this slow down my sheet a lot?

Answer (score 1):

Use this for getting the last row and it will see the last row, even if it is hidden.

```
LastRow = wsActiviteiten.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Comment: The UsedRange doesn't necessarily start in row 1. This is unreliable.

Comment: When I try it with the example that the OP suggested that we use, it works. So based on that... it seems to work just fine. o.O

Comment: I understand this can be unreliable, but in this specific macro, at that specific point, I think it may work. Thank you for your answer Rodger.

Comment: To add to my previous comment. I have tested this and it does what it says it does.

Comment: It may work for the case as tested, but `UsedRange` is unreliable as Excel routinely "forgets" the actual range and Rows.Count in this manner assumes there is data starting in row1.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found solution:

If you have at least one column in your range with 'consistent' data (all cells in that column are not empty/blank) you can use formula COUNTA and you can reference you code to value of that COUNTA formula.

For example:

Insert formula '=COUNTA(A1:A100000)' in 'B1' cell.

In B1 you will get how many rows you have they are hidden or not.

In your code change:

```
wsActiviteiten.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
```

to

```
wsActiviteiten.Range("A" & Range("B1").Value).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
```

Of course, if, for example, cell 'A2' is blank and this is the only blank cell you will need to adjust your formula to '=COUNTA(A1:A100000) +1'.

If you have more blank/empty cells and you don't know the exact number of them (blank cells have been changed dynamically) this method will not work.
As I said previously you need to have at least one column with 'consistent' data (with known number of empty cells in advance if any).